# Highcharts, x Axis Label / Ticks after Breaks

Tags: highcharts

Hello Stackoverflow Community,
i have a trouble with highcharts breaks for x axis.

[image: Chart without breaks]

[JSFiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/eaqowdmk/1/)

Point a value : Date 2014-12-11T11:24:49.000Z

point b value : Date 2014-12-11T17:50:47.734Z

point c value : Date 2014-12-19T16:19:26.000Z

point d value : Date 2014-12-21T20:51:52.000Z

My chart after adding a break like:

```
[...]
options.xAxis.breaks.push({from:pointb+1000, to: pointc-1000, breakSize: 1 })
[...]
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

[image: After breaks]

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eaqowdmk/2/)

Where are the xAxis tick's after the breaks ?

Answer (score 0):

Tick are placed on same positions as in a chart before the break was applied - `20. Dec`.

You can change how ticks are placed using, for example, [`tickInterval`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickInterval) and set it to 12 hours - `43200000`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/kwqqcx5b/